# ASP.Net MVC: No City data is showing in dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

i am showing data by webgrid. webgrid has textbox and dropdown to show name, state, city for each student etc. my code is working but wrong selected city is showing for each student. i populate my view model manually for easy testing purpose. here i am pasting my code. if possible please have a look and let me know the reason why wrong city is showing. what to change in code.
my full code is here

my dotnet fiddle link https://dotnetfiddle.net/BrKBx1

**please do not tell me to change model class design code.**

### ViewModel and Model

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public int SelectedState { get; set; }
    public int SelectedCity { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int StateID { get; set; }
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    public List<States> States { get; set; }
    public List<Cities> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class States
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Cities
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int StateID { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {

            MainViewModel oVm = new MainViewModel()
            {
                Students = new List<Student>() {
                        new Student
                        {
                            ID=1,
                            Name="JoyDev",
                            StateID=1,
                            CityID=1,
                            States=new List<States>()
                            {
                                new States
                                {
                                    ID=1,
                                    Name="WestBengal",
                                },
                                new States
                                {
                                    ID=2,
                                    Name="Bihar",
                                },
                                new States
                                {
                                    ID=3,
                                    Name="Orrisa",
                                }

                            },
                            Cities=new List<Cities>()
                            {
                                new Cities
                                {
                                    ID=1,
                                    Name="Alipur"
                                },
                                new Cities
                                {
                                    ID=2,
                                    Name="Asansol"
                                },
                                new Cities
                                {
                                    ID=3,
                                    Name="Andul"
                                }

                            }
                        },

    //***********
                        new Student
                        {
                            ID=2,
                            Name="Mukti",
                            StateID=2,
                            CityID=4,
                            States=new List<States>()
                            {
                                new States
                                {
                                    ID=1,
                                    Name="WestBengal",
                                },
                                new States
                                {
                                    ID=2,
                                    Name="Bihar",
                                },
                                new States
                                {
                                    ID=3,
                                    Name="Orrisa",
                                }

                            },
                            Cities=new List<Cities>()
                            {
                                new Cities
                                {
                                    ID=4,
                                    Name="Janpur"
                                },
                                new Cities
                                {
                                    ID=5,
                                    Name="Madhubani"
                                },
                                new Cities
                                {
                                    ID=6,
                                    Name="Kanti"
                                }

                            }
                        },
    //***********
                        new Student
                        {
                            ID=3,
                            Name="Somnath",
                            StateID=3,
                            CityID=9,
                            States=new List<States>()
                            {
                                new States
                                {
                                    ID=1,
                                    Name="WestBengal",
                                },
                                new States
                                {
                                    ID=2,
                                    Name="Bihar",
                                },
                                new States
                                {
                                    ID=3,
                                    Name="Orrisa",
                                }

                            },
                            Cities=new List<Cities>()
                            {
                                new Cities
                                {
                                    ID=7,
                                    Name="Chandapur"
                                },
                                new Cities
                                {
                                    ID=8,
                                    Name="Dhankauda"
                                },
                                new Cities
                                {
                                    ID=9,
                                    Name="Konarak"
                                }

                            }
                        }


                    }

            };

            return View(oVm);

        }
```

### view code

```
@model  BuildTable.Models.MainViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test Grid";
}

@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(null);
    grid.Bind(Model.Students);

}
@grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
        headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
        footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
        alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
        selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
        rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
        firstText: "<<",
        previousText: "<",
        nextText: ">",
        lastText: ">>",
        numericLinksCount: 5,
        columns:
            grid.Columns
            (
            grid.Column(columnName: "ID", header: "ID", format: @<text>@item.ID</text>,style:"SmallCols"),
            grid.Column(columnName: "FirstName", header: "First Name", format: @<text><input type="text" id="txtFirstName" value="@item.Name" class="edit-mode" /></text>,style:"NameColWidth" ),

            //grid.Column(columnName: "StateName", header: "State Name", format: @<text>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedState, new SelectList(Model.Students[1].States, "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedState = item.StateID), "-- Select States--", new { id = "cboState", @class = "edit-mode" })</text>,style:"NameColWidth"),

            grid.Column(columnName: "StateName", header: "State Name", format: @<text>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedState, new SelectList(Model.Students.SelectMany(x => x.States).Where(x => x.StateID == item.StateID), "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedState = item.StateID), "-- Select States--", new { id = "cboState", @class = "edit-mode" })</text>,style:"NameColWidth"),
            grid.Column(columnName: "CityName", header: "City Name", format: @<text>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCity, new SelectList(Model.Students.SelectMany(x => x.Cities).Where(x => x.ID == item.StateID), "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedCity = item.CityID), "-- Select City--", new { id = "cboCity", @class = "edit-mode" })
            </text>,style:"NameColWidth")
            ))
```

can't we filter like this way `(Model.Students.SelectMany(x => x.Cities).Where(x => x.StateID == item.StateID)`
the above code return all city data for each studen and there i am filtering city based on state id. if this is not right
code to do it then suggest me what to write to achieve the same. thanks

Comment: What cities are showing and what cities should be shown?

Comment: if u see fiddle link then u must notice no city is showing but when i populate student then i mention selected state and city id and also populate state and city for each student. so for each student city should come.

Comment: student id 1 has 3 states and 3 cities. so for student id 1 i want to show 3 states in dropdown and select one as per selected state id and the same way  i want to show 3 cities in dropdown and select one as per selected citie's state id.

Comment: Yes, that model definitely looks wrong to me (sorry, had to say it)

Comment: Why does `Student` store both a `StateID` _and_ a list of `States`??

Comment: @miparnisari probably u say put city and state property in main viewmodel instead of in student model but i want that each student must have states and city property.

Comment: state id in student model will store id of selected state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set the `StateID` of any of your cities, so if you filter by `StateID == item.StateID`, there will never be a match.

In your controller, you need something like this:

```
Cities = new List<Cities>()
{
    new Cities
    {
        ID = 4,
        StateID = 1, // add this!
        Name = "Janpur"
    },
    new Cities
    {
        ID = 5,
        StateID = 2, // add this!
        Name = "Madhubani"
    },
    new Cities
    {
        ID = 6,
        StateID = 3, // add this!
        Name = "Kanti"
    }
}
```

Also, I would recommend putting your `SelectLists` into a view model rather than creating them in the view. This will make your code easier to read, and just conceptually, a `SelectList`really is a type of model that supports a view, it's not the view itself.

---

Here's an updated fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UYpO9m

Comment: thanks for your code. here i again update the code in fiddle. so updated code with fiddle link as https://dotnetfiddle.net/GoJeBE

Answer (score 0):

Because your `Where` call comes *after* `SelectMany`. At that point, all you have is a collection of `Cities`, so when you filter that by `x.ID == item.StateID`, you saying only return `Cities` instances where `Cities.ID` equals `item.StateID`. None do, based on your test data, so nothing is returned. More likely than not, you simply need to move your `Where` call to *before* the `SelectMany` call, and then change the expression to `x.StateID == item.StateID` instead.

Comment: Sorry not very clear what u try to say. would mind to post code sample of what u said......thanks